# Printing a variable without assigning a value

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++, what happens if I print a variable that has not been assigned a value? The following two code gives me two different result. Also, the first one gives different result in each compilation and second one prints 0 every time. Why?

```
int main() {
    int x = 1;
    int y;   // No value has been assigned
    if (x) {
        cout << y;    // without using endl
        // prints different value each time
    }
}
```

vs.

```
int main() {
    int x = 1;
    int y;   // y is not initialized
    if (x) {
        cout << y << endl;    // using endl
        // prints 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Variables when declared have initial value that is a garbage value. Trying to use variables without initializing them will cause an UB.

Answer (score 5):

Reading an uninitialized value (more specifically, performing lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on an indeterminate value, which results from not initializing an object) has *undefined behaviour*; in other words, both programs are buggy.

Comment: Let's consider type `unsigned char`.

Comment: Current reference: [dcl.init]p12: "If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the behavior is undefined" (with a few exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

That variables are saved on the call-stack, that means the memory is allocated, when the program is started. And the program only knows where to read the variables from stack. The range where the program reads is just changed by calling a routine but not zeroed, and it may not be resetted when started program or used before. Some optimizations of your compiler may load or initializing something before calling the real main-procedure, what stands in connection to endl.

Just make a class with an output in constructor and initialize a variable of it it globally. Debug it, place a breakpoint in the constructor and you wouldn't see the main procedure on the call-stack.